# Loading indicator loads forever when clicking "close" on a question I already voted to close

Tags: bug, android-app

I wanted to retract a close vote. So I selected more/close

Result: the circle is spinning "forever", but no crash. Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> brought me back to the question.

[image]

Related but not a duplicate: [Voting to close a closed question crashes the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223075/voting-to-close-a-closed-question-crashes-the-android-app)